# Deprecation warning mocks won't be added automatically to load paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to Rails 3 I get this deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: "Rails.root/test/mocks/test" won't be added automatically to load paths anymore in future releases.
```

So how should this be implemted in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

Rails just checks for the existence of the mocks/test directory and spits out that warning if it exists.  Here is what the code looks like from rails/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:

```
if File.exists?("#{root}/test/mocks/#{Rails.env}")
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "\"RAILS_ROOT/test/mocks/#{Rails.env}\" won't be added " <<
          "automatically to load paths anymore in future releases"
        paths.mocks_path  "test/mocks", :load_path => true, :glob => Rails.env
      end
```

So it looks like this message will remain until they deprecate it.

If you need this path in your load path in the future, I think you just do something like this in config/application.rb (notice the comments taken directly from the config/application.rb template):

```
# Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
config.load_paths += %W( #{config.root}/test/mocks/#{Rails.env} )
```

I haven't tried it but this should help!

Comment: Looks like the way to go. My only concern is that you normally do not have mocks in production so there you'll be adding a directory that does not exist to the load path. I tried removing the development directory in development without seeing any errors so it may not be a problem? Are directories that do not exist just ignored?

Comment: Also, it should be config.autoload_paths since config.load_paths is also deprecated.